# How to avoid auto closing of XML tags after editing XML using transformers in java?

Tags: java, xml

My code is something like this and the output i get is

```
<DATA/>
```

instead of

```
<DATA></DATA>
```

Java code:

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING,document.getXmlEncoding());
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
document.setXmlStandalone(false); 
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);
StreamResult streamResult =
  new StreamResult(new File(filename));
transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
```

Comment: `<DATA></DATA>` and `<DATA/>` are 100% the same thing. Stop thinking about it, invest your time into actual problems.

Comment: Both are same i know, but somehwhere we need our output to be like this <DATA></DATA> only for better understanding and readblity

Comment: most probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161748/print-empty-xml-element-as-opening-tag-closing-tag

Comment: @Sanjeev: its not working

Comment: Which one you tried ?

Comment: @Sanjeev:The one u shared http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161748/print-empty-xml-element-as-opening-tag-closing-tag

Answer (score 0):

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();    

XMLStreamWriter sw =         
XMLOutputFactory.newFactory().createXMLStreamWriter(writer);

StAXResult streamResult = new StAXResult(sw);

System.setProperty("javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory",
"com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerFactoryImpl");

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING,document.getXmlEncoding());
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.VERSION, "1.0");
document.setXmlStandalone(false); 
DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(document);

transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult );
System.out.println(writer.toString());
```